# Summation $n times incremented matthematical loop

Tags: php, loops, math, sum

so I am stuck on this for a couple of hours and i just cannot figure out how to do it.

Here is what output i  want to accomplish:

if $n = 10 then we have sum ten times in a increment like this:
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10

```
function summation($n) {

     $start = 1;
     $end = $n;
     $sum = 0;

     for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {

         $value ="+";
         echo ++$sum, $value;

     }                     

}

summation(5);
```

Comment: apart from an extra "+" at the end, your function seems to do exactly what you want. so i guess i dont understand what you want, so what do you expect to be displayed from the above code?

Comment: the "+" must not be of the type string but a functioning + but i dont know how to sum them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function summation($n) {

 $start = 1;
 $end = $n;
 $sum = 0;
 for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
$sum+=$i; //add the $i varables up

}
echo $sum;
}

summation(10); //55
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Thanks! This works awesome, got to take a good look at it and figure out why i didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified:

```
$sum = array_sum(range(1, 10));
```

Comment: Nice that works also, i got it down to this:function summation($n, $b) {
if($n || $b >= 0 ) {
return $sum = array_sum(range($n, $b));
}else {
return false;
}
}

echo summation(1,3);